# AllocHGlobal equivalent in VB6

Tags: .net, api, vb6

All,

I have to write some share permission code in a legacy VB6 application. I know I will have to use API calls, and found a good example [here](http://www.nirajkachhadia.com/vbnet-programming.html). But I'm not clear on how to achieve some of the same functionality from VB6, mostly with memory allocation. For example:

```
pTrustee = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(t))
BuildTrusteeWithSid(pTrustee, pSID)
```

How would I do the same thing in VB6?

Answer (score 3):

For the memory allocation you can use this Win32 API function call:

```
Declare Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" Alias "GlobalAlloc" ( _
ByVal wFlags As Long, _
ByVal dwBytes As Long _
) As Long
```

[MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366574%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Similar MSDN pages for GlobalFree, GlobalLock and GlobalUnlock can be found at the [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383749%28VS.85%29.aspx)

For the BuildTrusteeWithSid method [MSDN is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376385%28VS.85%29.aspx). With links to TRUSTEE struct documentation.